# Can't get new ip from Tor using privoxy and stem

Tags: python, web-scraping, tor

I'm trying to rotate ip's using Tor, Privoxy and Stem but I end up getting always the same ip. I've tried several things (changing proxies, using request sessions, and a lot more) but with no success.

This is my python code:

```
import requests
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
  controller.authenticate('mykey')
  controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)

#proxies = {
#  "http": "http://127.0.0.1:8118"
#}

proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050',
    'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'
}

headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.73.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.1 Safari/537.73.11'
}
r = requests.get("http://icanhazip.com", proxies=proxies, headers=headers, stream=False)
print (r.text)
```

.torc file has this config

```
ExitNodes {ar}
StrictNodes 1

ControlPort 9051
HashedControlPassword 16:BA2B8B2EAC4B391060A6FAA27FA922706F08D0BA0115D79840265D9DC3
```

privoxy config file has this line

```
forward-socks5   /               127.0.0.1:9050 .
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found the problem. The IP Routing was working ok, the problem was that I'd been using the ExitNodes from {ar} and there's only one node for Argentina. So, it's always the same IP.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following method very handy and useful rather than the way you tried above. Make sure to put the right location of your `tor.exe` file within `torexe` variable. Proof of concept:

```
import requests
import os

torexe = os.popen(r"C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe")

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.proxies['http']  = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'
    res = s.get("http://icanhazip.com")
    print(res.text)

torexe.close()
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm not using Windows.